# Why does __sysChangeTxBsn receive a value with local updates but not remotely?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I have provisioned a SQL Server CE database with Microsoft Sync Framework. When I insert a new record remotely, the `__sysChangeTxBsn` column remains empty. When I copy the database to my local computer and insert a record locally, the `__sysChangeTxBsn` column receives a value, as expected. Why does change tracking work locally but not remotely?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a mismatch in SQL Server Compact version/service pack on the local and remote machines.

For future reference, here are the relevant links.

**SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP1**

- [Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 1 ... for Windows Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=5821)
- [Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 1 for Windows Mobile](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=17020)

**SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2**

- [Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 2 for Windows Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=5783)
- [Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 2 for Windows Mobile](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8831)

**Steps**

1. Choose to use either SP1 or SP2 but DO NOT mix the two!
2. Download and run the "for Windows Desktop" installer.
3. Download and run the "For Windows Mobile" installer.

If you're on an x64 computer and you chose SP2, after install your Add/Remove programs should look like this:

[image: Add/Remove Programs]

And you should have a directory at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5 that contains the relevant DLLs and CABs.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. I recall having these issues years ago working on a desktop app. Can be very painful.

Comment: @leppie Yes. It was extremely painful to determine the problem. Ten hours painful.